# How should I call a Restful Service

Tags: c#, rest

We have a class library project and a controller folder. In this folder we have a class called TravellerController.cs and it has a bunch of methods in there addorned with either [HttpGet] or [HttpPost]. I have placed this in IIS.

When I try and make a webRequest I always receive a 404 error. I think it's because I'm calling it in the form

```
 var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:80/MyClassLibrary/Traveller/GetProductCode/" + product + "/" + subProduct);
```

Where GetProductCode is the method on the class. I think the trouble is that there is no actual web page at this address which is why it fails. How should I be calling the method in a restful way.

Comment: is ur url working in browser?

Comment: Can you show the controller method you are trying to hit?

Comment: No, as I said there's no page to this, it all gets compiled into a Dll the Physical path when browsing via IIS, is looking for a file called Traveller which doesn't exist. Renaming to TravellerContoller will not work for the same reason as it get's compiled into the dll.

Comment: This is the method I'm trying to call`[HttpGet]`
`public string GetProductCode(Products product, SubProducts subProduct)`
`{`
   `return SubProductProductCode.GetProductCode(product, subProduct); }`

Comment: Please update your answer with the code. Thank you.

Comment: ur url is not correct

Comment: @Awais.....I know that's what I want help with......how do I call it.

Comment: @Nick L after the initial line of code in my question I set the `request.Method = 'GET'``var webResponse = request.GetResponse();`

Comment: For Web Api it should be 

localhost:80/api/traveller/getproductcode?product=yourproduct&SubProduct=yoursubproduct

Comment: @Awis, changing my call to include api and changing the parameter call still gives me 404 error

Comment: @Awis, I have changed the request to your updated version, but it still gives a 404. In IIS I have tried to configure it as an application under the Default site and also as a site in it's own right (not at the same time), both give the same results.

Comment: replace this in your RouteConfig.cs with the existing one:

routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: @Awis, because this is a Dll I dont have a RouteConfig file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check out that your API service is up and running properly.

By what you mentioned, the path `http://localhost:80/MyClassLibrary/Traveller/GetProductCode/<product>/<subProduct>` does not seem to be right. Are you sure you need the `/Traveller/` in your path?

Also, make sure you are passing the right arguments to your service and you are requesting to the right port.

When you manage get content, use a parser, such as [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library (if using JSON format) to parse the content and use it.

Comment: Hi Nick, that's what I'm not sure about. In standard code I'd instantiate the Traveller class and then call the method. because I'm using WebApi, I'd assume that the Traveller class would need to be part of the address

Comment: In your case, I would check where to set the paths of the API calls.

Comment: I think the issue is with IIS. I have created a new site and given it a port of 8060 so that the port number is unique, I have set the physical path to point to my BIN directory. I can see the MyClassLibrary.dll in there, and I have changed my call to be     `http://localhost:8060/api/MyClassLibrary/GetProductCode?product=myProduct&SubProduct=mySubProduct` When I browse and it errors, part of the physical path shows the /api/ making it look as though it's looking for a directory called api which of course doesn't exist